# bundler (1.6.2) load 'set' failed on index.rb:1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm facing a weird problem on bundler when I was playing around with my rails app.

### Env

- ruby 2.1.1
- rails 4.1.0
- bundler 1.6.2

I also tried: ruby 2.0.0, rails 4.0.0. bundle 1.6.0, 1.3.5, none of them works.

### What I tried

When I tried `rails -v` it reports:

`` `require': cannot load such file -- set (LoadError)
/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/index.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' ``

Then I took a look at `index.rb`, the first line is:

`require "set"`

Then I tried:

`irb(main):001:0> require 'set'
=> true
irb(main):002:0>`

### Question

- What's wrong?
- What should I do to recover this?

Comment: Tried `bundle exec rails -v`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out that my `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` had some problem, I tried to use this `rbenv` at that moment, but later, I switched to raw installation. And it worked.